# Rest call from GWT, DomRepresentation not returning Dom

Tags: java, gwt, restlet

Using Restlet for the backend service, unit tested remote and local returns XML no problem, when called from GWT, the response comes back but no XML attached.
    ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://-env.elasticbeanstalk.com/v1_0/admin/getAllUsers/");

```
    clientResource.setOnResponse(new Uniform() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
            DomRepresentation domRepresentation = new DomRepresentation(response.getEntity());

            try {
                Document document = domRepresentation.getDocument();
                Element listElement = (Element)document.getFirstChild();
```

listElement is null

Is there anyone out there using GWT version of Restlet, not many examples on the net, I have ran this in debug mode the response comes back but no XML attached.

Comment: Did you check the response status code? Did you manually set the content-type?

Comment: Solved this issue, for anybody else having this problem, status Code all good content type set:

Comment: It was a cross domain issue needed to set the Access-control-Allow-origin see below

Comment: Series<Header> responseHeaders = (Series<Header>) getResponseAttributes().get(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);

        if(responseHeaders == null){
            responseHeaders = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
            getResponseAttributes().put(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, responseHeaders);
        }

        responseHeaders.add(new Header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"));

Comment: Sorry hitting enter posts the reply.